# How to create a flag from regular expressions in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a dataset with IDs and a phone number as a string. I need to build a flag to show if the string is in a valid format.

Here's a dummy dataset.

```
CREATE TABLE Test 
(
    ID int, 
    Cell varchar(11)
) 

INSERT INTO Test (ID, Cell) 
VALUES (1, '07123456789'), 
       (2, '441234567');
```

For now, a simple flag that indicates it started with a 0, for example, would be a good starting point for me. I've managed to figure out that `Cell LIKE '^0%'` should make that work, but I can't figure out how to build it into a Boolean flag.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have regular expressions. SQL, the language, is a query language and historically weak in text processing. How is the data loaded? The best place to check formats like this is the import code, not SQL.

Comment: you can add a computed column to your create table, like: `, ValidPhone as Cell LIKE '0%'`

Comment: Add a check constraint that rejects invalid phone numbers.

Comment: What conditions must be satisfied to make your flag be 1? If the only condition is the string should start with a 0, you can simply use `LEFT`: `...CASE LEFT(Cell,1) WHEN '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END...`

Answer (score 1):

You use a case expression (or inline-if) for this:

```
Select case when Cell like '0%' then 1 else 0 end as MyFlag
from...

Select iif(Cell like '0%', 1, 0) as MyFlag
from...
```